# PHP кодировка в PDF с ирглифами

Tags: php, pdf, кодировка

Подскажи те плиз. все pdf-ки открываются хорошо, но вот попалась одна. При открытии в ридере типа Evince все гуд, но стоит скопироать текст все в вопросах и иероглифах. В php также. Чем можно помочь?

Пример:

```
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÅÉÇÅÇÇÄÃÅÁ

mb_detect_encoding // utf-8
```

Comment: Там у вас написано `юабцдефгхеигеггдцеа`? :)

Comment: С чего бы вдруг?)

Comment: Просто похоже, что это какая-то однобайтная кодировка отображается в виде Win1252. Вот блок-схема для распознания кодировок https://habrahabr.ru/post/147843/

Comment: Исходный текст "Thank you for booking" )